# Как опустить сайтбары вниз страницы в мобильной версии сайта?

Tags: html, wordpress

У меня на странице есть справа сайтбары. В мобильной версии ни становятся сверху основного контента траницы. Как перенести их в мобильной версии вниз страницы?

Comment: Скорее всего это не сайтбары, а сайдбары (от слова sidebar). А касательно вашего вопроса, если вёрстка flex то используйте order к элементам в нужном вам порядке.

Comment: к сожалению верстка на float

Comment: Могу заблуждаться, но вроде как это невозможно сделать кроме как создать копию объекта в нужном вам месте и использовать display none по медиа запросам. Либо же на javascript "клонировать\переносить" блок. Или же попробуйте обернуть все элементы во flexbox